# Changing locale in flutter web causes app to fade

Tags: android, flutter, web

I am creating an app in flutter and the client's requirement is also to create PWA of the app in Flutter Web, now I am having issues regarding flutter web which hopefully can be solved with your help.

I hav build an apk and it is working as desired. Screen Shots are attached.

[image: Language select]
[image: english language]

Now, these both Screenshots are of apk. Coming to flutter web, there is no issue in laptop/PC, but if we run webapp which is hosted, on mobile it starts causing problems. Screen shots of web are attached.

[image: Language select]
[image: english language]

As you can see, there is clear difference between apk screenshots and web app screen shots. When I select English the text fades, even english in the dialogue box is faded.